# Display the featured image from the last post

Tags: categories, images, post-thumbnails

I am building a category overview page and i am use this code:

```
<?php
    $limit      = 999;
    $counter    = 0;
    $categories = get_categories();

    foreach ($categories as $category):
        if ($counter < $limit) {
            $args  = array(
                'category__in' => array(
                    $category->term_id
                ),
                'caller_get_posts' => 1
            );
            $posts = get_posts($args);
            if ($posts) {
                echo '<div class="category">';
                echo '<a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '" title="' . sprintf(__("View all posts in %s"), $category->name) . '" ' . '>';
                echo '<h3>' . $category->name . '</h3>';
                echo '</a>';
                echo '</div>';

            }
        }

    $counter++;
    endforeach;
?>
```

But how to insert in the echo that the featured image from the last post in that category will be displayed.

Comment: Do you want to show featured image of the latest post of each category??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [Mat](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/37985/mat) his code and fixed some duplicated issue.

**The code that works like a charm**:

```
<?php
    $limit      = 999;
    $counter    = 0;
    $categories = get_categories();

    foreach ($categories as $category):
        if ($counter < $limit) {
            $args  = array(
                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                'cat' => $category->cat_ID,
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
            );
            $posts = get_posts($args);
            if ($posts) {
                    echo '<div class="category">';
                    while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                        the_post_thumbnail();
                    endwhile;
                    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '" ' . '>';
                    echo '<h3>' . $category->name . '</h3>';
                    echo '</a>';
                    echo '</div>';
            }
        }

    $counter++;
    endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. I've modified your `$args` a little and surrounded your echoed code within the `while(have_posts()) : the_post();` loop, then added the `the_post_thumbnail()` function and, finally, the `wp_query_reset();` at the bottom:

```
<?php
    $limit      = 999;
    $counter    = 0;
    $categories = get_categories();

    foreach ( $categories as $category ):
        if ( $counter < $limit ) {
            $args  = array(
                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                'cat' => $category->cat_ID,
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
            );
            $posts = get_posts( $args );

            while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                echo '<div class="category">';
                the_post_thumbnail();
                echo '<a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '" title="' . sprintf(__("View all posts in %s"), $category->name) . '" ' . '>';
                echo '<h3>' . $category->name . '</h3>';
                echo '</a>';
                echo '</div>';
            endwhile;

        }

    $counter++;
    endforeach;

    wp_query_reset();

?>
```

Ps. `caller_get_posts` is deprecated since version 3.1! Use `ignore_sticky_posts` instead in your `$args`

Comment: Hi Mat, this is working but now i get the image and the title of the category in the div and after that it will make a other div category with only the title inside it. (this for every category its somehows duplicate but only with the title?)

Comment: @Maanstraat - Can you provide screenshot so I can see what you mean?

Comment: i fxed it already (see the answer under you)